# Change an objects `color` when a dark section is behind it using IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I tried doing this with `mix-blend-mode` but don't get the desired effect so I've decided I need to use JavaScript to change the colour.

I have a fixed header at the top of the page. As well as some other elements which are centred/positioned outside the header. These are black in colour by default. But I have a series of fullbleed 100% height/width image banners and sometimes when the text in the fixed elements moves over a certain image, the text isn't very legible.

I had the idea to tag each section with a `data-` attribute. So if `data-color="dark` is set for example, I can target that to invert the colour of the text when it enters that sections and switches back when it leaves it.

This seems to work OK for the head elements but I feel like it would be better if the centred prev/next links changed when the `section` was closer, rather than when it hits the top edge of the page. Likewise with the `.page-name` but that's not quite as vital.

```js
const header = document.querySelector('[data-header]')
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-section]')]
const scrollRoot = document.querySelector('[data-scroller]')
const headerLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-link]')]

let prevYPosition = 0
let direction = 'up'

const options = {
    root: scrollRoot,
    rootMargin: `${header.offsetHeight * -1}px`,
    threshold: 0
}

const getTargetSection = (entry) => {
    const index = sections.findIndex((section) => section == entry.target)
    
    if (index >= sections.length - 1) {
     return entry.target
    } else {
     return sections[index + 1]
    }
}

const updateColors = (target) => {
    const theme = target.dataset.section
    header.setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
  document.querySelector('.page-name').setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
  document.querySelector('.page-nav').setAttribute('data-theme', theme)
}

const shouldUpdate = (entry) => {
    if (direction === 'down' && !entry.isIntersecting) {
        return true
    }

    if (direction === 'up' && entry.isIntersecting) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}

const onIntersect = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (scrollRoot.scrollTop > prevYPosition) {
            direction = 'down'
        } else {
            direction = 'up'
        }
        
        prevYPosition = scrollRoot.scrollTop
        
        const target = direction === 'down' ? getTargetSection(entry) : entry.target
        
        if (shouldUpdate(entry)) {
            updateColors(target)
        }
    })
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersect, options)

sections.forEach((section) => {
    observer.observe(section)
})
```

```css
/* Body */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Variables */
:root {
    --dark: #fff;
  --light: #000;
}

/* Header */

.header {
  padding: 16px 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Nav */

.nav-main {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-main__item {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.nav-main__link {
  color: currentcolor;
}

/* Name Page */

.page-name {
  color: currentcolor;
  display: block;
  rotate: -180deg;
  margin: 80px 0 32px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  max-height: calc(50vh - 128px);
}

/* Grid Overlay */

.grid--faux {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 0 32px;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100vw - 64px);
  z-index: 10;
}

.page-prev,
.page-next {
  color: currentcolor;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* Main Content */

.section {
  background: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.section--dark {
  background: #444;
  color: white;
}

[data-theme="light"] {
    color: black;
}

[data-theme="dark"]  {
    color: white;
}

.scroller {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" data-header>
  <ul class="nav-main">
    <li class="nav-main__item"><a href="#" class="nav-main__link" data-link>Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-main__item"><a href="#" class="nav-main__link" data-link>Work</a></li>
    <li class="nav-main__item"><a href="#" class="nav-main__link" data-link>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="grid--faux">
  <p class="page-name" data-page>Name of template</p>
  <a href="#" class="page-nav page-prev" data-nav>Prev</a>
  <a href="#" class="page-nav page-next" data-nav>Next</a>
</div>

<div class="main scroller" data-scroller>
  <section class="section section--dark" data-section="dark">
    Fixed text should display white when over this section.this
  </section>
  <section class="section" data-section="light">
    Fixed text should display black when over this section.
  </section>
  <section class="section section--dark" data-section="dark">
    Fixed text should display white when over this section.
  </section>
  <section class="section" data-section="light">
    Fixed text should display black when over this section.
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors. The snippet gives 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'color')",' The problem seems to be with querySelectorAll - should that be querySelector?

Comment: I found a different script which seems to do the job for the header but guess I need to duplicate code for the page name and nav again? https://jsfiddle.net/xkbsf09m/1/

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth, I've fixed those errors / update the example in the post which is a lot closer to 'working'